# BJAM , building for vc-80 instead of vc7.1

Tags: c++, windows, boost, bjam

How can i build a boost library date_time using bjam for vc80.

currently I am using 
..\bjam.exe release debug threa
ding=multi --toolset=msvc-8.0 stage --with-date_time --build-type=complete --deb
ug-configuration -d+2
This only generates libraries with the vc7.1 version, what I need is vc80.

I also noticed that the v1 verion Boost.Build setup was being used instead of the v2.
So user_config.jam was not being used.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right:

```
..\bjam.exe release debug threading=multi toolset=msvc-8.0 stage \
    --with-date_time --build-type=complete --debug-configuration -d+2
```

Note: no dashes for the option `toolset`.